# Extremely long net in Xilinx synthesized design labeled "async_path". What's it for?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vivado

I used Vivado to synthesize a small design for the Xilinx xc7k-160t-1. The design includes a fifo instantiated with Vivado's XPM macros which crosses clock domains from 100.8MHz to 200MHz.

When I opened the synthesized design, I saw these extremely long nets that used routing resources for no apparent purpose; the start and end of the nets are in adjacent cells, but they're routed way out to the edges of the chip! There are about 20 of them; I think they're connected to the gray counters in the CDC fifos.

[image]

**My question:** Does anyone know why Vivado synthesizes these extremely long nets? Is there a reason that Vivado is doing this intentionally, or is it a sign of an issue in my design / constraints?

My design is deployed to an Opal Kelly xem7360 module. The xdc/sdc file for this module can be downloaded [here](https://pins.opalkelly.com/pin_list/XEM7360), but the snippet relevant to my clocks is below:

```
create_clock -name okUH0 -period 9.920 [get_ports {okUH[0]}]
create_clock -name sys_clk -period 5 [get_ports sys_clkp]
set_clock_groups -asynchronous -group [get_clocks {sys_clk}] -group [get_clocks {okUH0}]
```

One of my clock domains is the 100.8MHz `okUH[0]` clock, the other is the 200MHz `sys_clk`.

I can add a minimal reproducible example to my question if people want.

Comment: What are your SDC constraints

Comment: Edited my question to include this info, thanks.

Comment: When you make two clocks asynchronous group in sdc, router now has the liberty to route inter-clock paths in however way it wants because timing is not taken into account on such paths. This could be the issue.

Comment: This is a CDC crossing, and you will have to properly constrain that. The Xilinx IP should include the correct SDC constraints. (Maybe you have this, just don't use it? You also should read the latest documentation.)